# Rails - find records without specific type of associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have three models:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :projects, through: :assignments
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :people, through: :assignments
end

class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :project
end
```

In my `assignment` model I am using a 'kind' attribute to determine the types of relationships.  At the moment assignments come in the following kinds:  "Supervisor", "Worker", "Inspector".  In the future there will likely be more kinds of assignments.

I am having trouble writing Active Record scopes to find projects which are lacking assignments of a specific type. For example at the moment I am using the following to find projects which have workers assigned.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.assigned_workers
    joins(:assignments).where(assignments: { :kind => 'worker' })
  end
end
```

How would I write the opposite of the above example, and find projects which have no assigned workers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a left join for this. Unfortunately Rails doesn't make this easy. But you can still use SQL fragments:

```
joins("LEFT JOIN assignments ON assignments.project_id = projects.id AND assignments.kind = 'worker'").where(assignments: {id: nil})
```

So SQL does a LEFT JOIN on assignments where the assignment kind is 'worker', but only selects rows for which there was no matching assignment.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, would this approach be better than running a NOT IN query?   `where.not(id: assigned_workers.pluck(:id))`

Comment: I would prefer it since it does it in a single query. In your example here, assigned_workers.pluck(:id) runs a first query, whose result gets used int he second query. The other advantage of the single-query is it's easier to turn this into an association: `has_many :assigned_non_workers, ->{<joins & where here>}, class_name: "Person"`. This allows you now to use Project.joins(:assigned_non_workers), which is pretty cool. You can't do that if you pluck ids related to a specific instance.

Comment: Sorry, the association def needs work because of the :through, but I ran out of edit time on the comment. But it's definitely possible with some work.

Comment: I think you could defined the association types on Assignment: `has_many :non_workers, ->{<left join & where conditions>}, class_name: "Person"`, then use in Project `has_many :assigned_non_workers, through: :assignments, source: :non_workers`

Comment: Similarly, you might consider changing your assigned_workers method into an association, which is easier: Assignment `has_many :workers, ->{where kind: 'worker'}, class_name: "Person"`, and Project `has_many :workers, through: :assignments, source: :workers` (I don't believe you need `:class_name` for this association but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, I've been pulling my hair out on this one for a while.  I even thought about separating the different types of people out into their own models, all over this query.  Your answer is concise and works well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Rails 4.0+, You could negate the one above:

```
joins(:assignments).where.not(assignments: { :kind => 'worker' })
```

This would give you all the projects that do not have workers assigned.

Comment: Wouldn't this approach just select the Projects which have other people assigned? Even if a Project has no workers assigned it can still have a supervisor, or an inspector.

Comment: It will take all the projects that have assignments that are not of type worker.

> Even if a Project has no workers assigned

Could you then give me an example of a project that has workers assigned?